# Can you use Okta REST API to login a user and get SAML2 response back

Tags: saml-2.0, okta, okta-api

We have a successful implementation of SSO with Okta as the IdP and an external PHP site as a SP. We are currently utilizing the Okta Sign On Widget which sends our PHP SP a SAML2 Token.

Question is, can we now change from the widget to the API and still get the SAML 2 token on successful login via the API?

Answer (score 1):

So, Since posting this I figured out that - 'yes you can'. I don't know if this is the cleanest/best way but it works and here is how to do it in case anyone else gets stuck looking into this issue...

1. Already having SAML2 communication working between Okta as IdP and
   PHP site as SP.
2. Create an API access token in Okta.
3. Use the access token to post a request for a one-time use token from
   the API for a specific user you want to login as:
   http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/sessions.html
4. Redirect the user with the retrieved one-time session token to your
   App's embed link with the one-time session token:
   http://developer.okta.com/docs/examples/session_cookie.html#retrieving-a-session-cookie-by-visiting-an-application-embed-link
5. This will log the user into Okta to get a proper session we can then
   use to send to our PHP end-point to get the SAML2 token we want but
   while utilizing the full customization benefits of the API.